# ¿Cómo saber si un valor existe en un hash de Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Resulta que necesito saber si un valor de un hash existe, y que devuelva `true` o un `puts "Este producto existe"`
y en el caso de que no, también, un `return false` o un `puts"Este producto no existe"`.

Ejemplo:

```
productos = { xbox => 120, play => 140 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el método [Hash#has_key?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F):

```
productos = { xbox: 120, play: 140 }

productos.has_key?(:xbox)
#=> true

productod.has_key?(:nes)
#=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método `include?` de la siguiente forma:

```
productos = { xbox: '120', play: '140'}

productos.keys
# => [:xbox, :play]

productos.values
# => ["120", "140"]
```

Ahora que tienes un `Array` ya sea con las llaves (`keys`) o los valores (`values`), puedes uilizar `include?` para determinar si hay un valor o llave presente.

```
productos = { xbox: '120', play: '140'}

productos.keys.include?('xbox')
# => true

productos.keys.include?('nintendo')
# => false

productos.values.include?('120')
# => true

productos.values.include?('100')
# => false
```

Ahora, para que regrese una frase (`String`) como 'Este producto existe' puedes utilizar una condicional `if`/`else`

```
if productos.keys.include?('xbox')
   # cuando regresa true
   'Este producto existe'
else
   # cuando regresa false
   'Este producto no existe'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentando ampliar un poco más las posibles respuesta de mis compañeros, hay que decir de que si te decides por devolver un `String`, no es necesario llamar a ningún método como `Hash#has_key?` o `Hash#keys` si el valor por defecto del hash es `nil`:

```
def existe_producto?(productos, nombre)
  if productos[nombre]
    'Este producto existe'
  else
    'Este producto no existe'
  end
end

productos = { xbox: '120', play: '140'}

existe_producto?(productos, :xbox)
# => 'Este producto existe'

existe_producto?(productos, :wii)
# => 'Este producto no existe'
```

Esto es debido, a que por defecto cuando se crea un Hash, si se intenta acceder a una nueva clave que no está definida, está te devuelve `nil`:

```
productos[:wii]
# => nil
```

El valor por defecto de un Hash se puede cambiar llamando a [`Hash::new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) en vez de utilizar el literal para definir un Hash:

```
productos = Hash.new('No existe')
productos[:xbox] = 120

productos[:xbox]
# => 120

productos[:wii]
# => 'No existe'
```

Saludos.